# OAuth port for Python 3

Tags: oauth, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I am trying to create a Twitter and StatusNet client in python 3 but I have a problem, all the examples I find use the OAuth library. There is some example using just curl or a simple authentication but it is very basic.

Do you know if there is a port of OAuth (1 or 2) for Python 3 ?

Thank you

---

**Update** : maybe the lack of port is explained by the [lack of good python 2 implementation](http://pydanny.github.com/the-sorry-state-of-python-oauth-providers.html) ?

Comment: It doesn't look like it according to http://onpython3yet.com/packages/show/oauth

Comment: No official but maybe somebody developed one

Comment: I think the poor state of Python oauth libraries goes some way to explain it. It [looks like](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=oauth&submit=search) everyone is solving their own problem with oauth, but no one library has really emerged as the best solution. The requests library now supports Python 3, so you might start with the ones in that list that claim to add oauth to that ([requests-oauth2](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth2) and [requests-oauth](https://github.com/maraujop/requests-oauth)).

Comment: Maybe indeed. I'll test it with a bit of 2to3. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [python oauthlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauthlib) client which supports python2/3 and oauth1/2.

According to [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Python/3):

> If your application is using OAuth, port your code from the old, unmaintained, OAuth1-only, Python 2-only oauth library (i.e. python-oauth) to the new, maintained, OAuth1 and OAuth2 compatible, Python 2 and Python 3 compatible oauthlib (i.e. python-oauthlib) package. Porting is not so hard, although some of the terminology updates in the OAuth spec since the original oauth was released make it a bit trickier.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to update my question. I have been using requests-oauthlib (https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib) which is based on python oauthlib.